# .NET Framework not found when debugging a project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to VS2012. When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute the project, I get an error:

> Warning   1   The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETCore,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the
>   SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your
>   application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK
>   or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved
>   from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
>   reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly
>   targeted for the framework you intend.

I have installed .NET Framework 4.5 and I've also picked *repair*, but I'm still facing this error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you targetted your project at .NET 4.5? Click the project file, then press Alt+Enter, and check what it says in the application tab.

Comment: I'd guess you are actually using the Express edition and you've got the wrong version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your project. Choose Properties and change the Target framework to 4.5.
[image]